# Which branch applies more to programming: Calculus or Linear Algebra

Tags: math

I'm a comp sci student and I need to fill out my math electives. Which would apply more to programming and computer science? Hell, which would be more useful altogether?

Elementary Calculus or Linear Algebra?

There are both second tier classes (level two) and I can only choose one.

If it boils down to a coin toss, I'll go with which ever fits into my schedule better... But really, I'd like to know which is best...

Thanks!

Comment: Just a little update:
I'm three quarters through my first year as a Comp Sci. student and I've come to the conclusion that both Calc and Lin. Alg are applicable, depending what you want to do. Calculus has definitely helped me tackle harder programming problems and Lin. Algebra has forced me to think more abstractly.

My question should have been asked within the context of what I want to do with my career. I find Machine Learning to be interested and I'm told Linear Algebra is more applicable to it... So that'll be my focus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have spent more than a decade working in very advanced linear algebra, so you might think I would recommend linear algebra.  In fact, I recommend calculus.  The reason is simple: if someone hasn't learned linear algebra, I can teach them the basics very quickly, assuming they already know calculus.  If they haven't mastered calculus, they wouldn't be as competitive for a job and they wouldn't know enough to begin a lot of different optimization methods, which can be applicable to many types of functions, not just those that arise in typical linear algebra manipulations. Teaching the methods of calculus simply takes a lot more time and effort than that for linear algebra, at least at the level of a basic education.

Answer (score 1):

Throw a coin because they both are.

You could assign to one but, attempt two.

Answer (score 1):

Linear Algebra is more immediately applicable in a computational setting, but the distinction is very slight, and I think you'll get more value overall from learning calculus (and even that's a line-call).

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find more beneficial knowledge in linear algebra.  Calculus will be more likely applicable to an Engineering setting, but linear algebra can come into play in many programming endeavors.  Particularly in Video Game development, where most young programmers aspire to be :-)

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, Linear Algebra if you go into graphics, otherwise neither.  You mileage may vary

Comment: And what is your experience ?

Comment: Coding for a consulting company in the real world for the last 6 years